# Removing left margin from first element and right margin from 3 element

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="element"></div> <!-- remove left margin -->
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div> <!-- remove right margin -->
    <div class="element"></div> <!-- remove left margin -->
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div> <!-- remove right margin -->
    <div class="element"></div> <!-- remove left margin -->
</div>
```

the number of elements needs to be variable, but 3 in a row.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you are looking for is the [`:nth-child()`-Slector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).
With that you can e.g. say that every third element needs to remove the left margin .

[Your example on JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/319cs6Lk/)

```
/* remove margin-right from every third child */
.element:nth-child(3n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: yes i did with :nth-child(3n) :nth-child(3n - 2) :nth-child(3n +1) :first-child. But the strange thing is that it issent working like it should be.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem? Please create a JSFiddle with your code or update mine to show where your problem is.

Comment: if you want look at this link you can see my problem. http://development.vivars.nl/schoolproject/front.html (still working on the responsive ness)

Comment: `nth-child` takes every child into consideration that is on the same level as your content-cards. Read [the difference between nth-child and nth-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/), then decide either to try it again with nth-of-type or use row-wraps to separate content-cards and other elements like your breadcrumbs.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Would you mind accepting my answer then? :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.test{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left:0px;
  margin-right:0px;
}
.element:nth-child(1) {
    margin-left:0px; 
}
.element:nth-child(3) {
    margin-right:0px; 
}
.element{
  height:50px;
  width:150px;
  background-color:pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div class="test">
    <div class="element"></div> <!-- remove left margin -->
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div> <!-- remove right margin -->
    </div>
 <div class="test">
    <div class="element"></div> <!-- remove left margin -->
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div> <!-- remove right margin -->
    </div>
  <div class="test">
    <div class="element"></div> <!-- remove left margin -->
    </div>
</div>
```